# Jquery ajax validation before form submit issues

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying validate captcha using ajax, Even if return value false form is submitting, where is my fault?

```
<form id="myid" name="formname" method="post" action="action.php"  onsubmit="return validate();">
```

**JS**

```
function validate()
{
if(document.getElementById('cap').value==''){
    alert("Please enter verification number shown in below image");
    document.getElementById('cap').focus();
    return false;
}  

var capval=document.getElementById('cap').value;

capcheck(capval).success(function (data) {
    //alert(data); not getting alert message
  if(data == "fail"){return false;} 
});
// return false; (if I use this, above alert works gives outputs either ok or fail
}
////
function capcheck(capvalue){
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'check_cap.php',
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        data: {
           capid:capvalue
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the check is asynchronic. You can cancel the form submit and later when the request to validate returns, submit it.

Try something like this

in html

```
onsubmit="return validate(this);"
```

in js

```
function validate(form)
{
    if(document.getElementById('cap').value==''){
        alert("Please enter verification number shown in below image");
        document.getElementById('cap').focus();
        return false;
    }  

    var capval=document.getElementById('cap').value;

    capcheck(capval).success(function (data) {
      if(data != "fail") {
        form.submit(); // HERE IS THE ASYNC SUBMIT
      }
      else alert('form error: '+ data);
    });
    return false; // ALWAYS PREVENT SUBMIT ON CLICK OR ENTER
}
```

Comment: as I am not familiar for these stuffs, I have doubt I already place onsubmit function call in form, Will it fall in infinite loop?

Comment: Good question... test it and let us know :)

Comment: your code validating successfully, but not submitting, any other changes has to be do?

Comment: try this on html `onsubmit="return validate(this);"` and add parameter in js `function validate(form)`, also remove the line `var form = this;`, tell me if it works

Comment: are you still getting an infinite loop?